# MySQL: Look for specific value first then get a second value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My code so far

```
SELECT * FROM gp 
WHERE status IN ('priority', NULL)  
   AND (status='priority' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gp WHERE status IS NULL)) 
LIMIT 1
```

I'm trying to get the first row with `status = 'priority'` if one exists, or else get the first row with `status = NULL`. There may be other values for status as well, but I only want to get `priority` first if available, then `NULL`.

What my code does so far is, it returns the rows with `status = 'priority'` when they exist, but returns nothing when only `NULL`s exist.

Comment: If I use ORDER BY, it has to be DESC to get the 'priority' before NULL. But with DESC I also get the last 'priority' or NULL first.

Comment: What defines the "first" row?

Comment: The order they were imported in - order of the id's. The normal ASC order

Comment: Remember: database tables are **unordered** by definition. If you don't have an `ORDER BY` _somewhere_, things may _seem_ to come back in a stable, sensible sorted order, but that's only because it's convenient for the database right now. Then the day comes where you add a new index, or a patch adds the round-robin performance optimization you see in other databases, or a maintenance job re-orders the pages on disk. Suddenly that old ordering is no longer the most convenient option, and your query breaks. Or rather, you find out your query was always broken, and you'd just gotten away with it.

Comment: Part two. I see this: `The order they were imported in - order of the id's`. This is also _**not reliable**_. There are things which can alter the default sequencing of those IDs. If this ordering really matters, you should consider adding a column to capture the timestamp at the time the record is created.

Comment: Thanks Joel, for the comments. For now I used an ORDER BY id, it was enough for that project. Definitely timestamps are the way to go where precision is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `NULL` in an `IN` expression, so you need to change the first part of your `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE status = 'priority' OR status IS NULL
```

You can remove the second part of the `WHERE` clause and simply

```
ORDER BY status = 'priority` DESC
```

this will put rows which have `status = 'priority'` ahead of those which have `status` of `NULL`

So your query as a whole becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM gp 
WHERE status = 'priority' OR status IS NULL
ORDER BY status = 'priority` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that to get the "first" row with `status = 'priority'` you need an ordering column (SQL tables are unordered, so without an ordering column "first" has no meaning), and you can add that to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM gp 
WHERE status = 'priority' OR status IS NULL
ORDER BY status = 'priority` DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will put the last records first of either type. I'd like to get the very first of each.

Comment: @nieburr There's no real definition of "first" without a column to order by; see my edit. Do you have an `id` column or the like which defines what "first" is?

Comment: @nieburr I've updated the answer by adding `id` to the `ORDER BY` clause; this will give you the "first" row of either type